# Java Removing Characters from XML

Tags: java, xml, dom, escaping

I'm reading XML data using Java and DOM. When I print a variable to the console I notice it prints on two different lines.

**Output:**

```
Hello How are
you today?
```

When I go to the attribute I'm trying to print of the underlying XML document, I notice the following:

```
<element attribute = "Hello How are&#xD;&#xA;you today?"></element>
```

How do I remove the characters `&#xD;&#xA;` from the attribute value in Java?

If the data from the attribute is stored in a Java String variable called myVar, I tried the following unsuccessfully:

```
if(myVar.contains("&#xD;&#xA;")){

    myVar = myVar.replaceAll("&#xD;&#xA;", " ");

}
```

Comment: Try replacing \r and \n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replaceAll("\\s+", " ")` worked but so did `replaceAll("\r\n", " ")`. On the other hand, `"\n\r"` as first argument to replaceAll did not work.

Answer (score 2):

`&#xD;&#xA;` this is a line break embedded in XML, which is probably converted into characters 0xD 0xA (13 10) in java. So for the pattern, either use "\n\r", or use "\s+" -> " "

Comment: If he's using `replaceAll`, he should use `"\\s+"` since it takes a regular expression as its first argument. Using `"s+"` will just replace instances of 1 or more s characters.

Comment: Should probably be "\r\n" instead of "\n\r".